# How can I set the widths of some input fields on one line?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I'm having an awful lot of trouble figuring out how to make the widths of my input fields make sense.

I've tried as many CSS properties as I could think of but none of them seem to work as expected. I tried Width with percentages and EMs, I tried display: table and table-cell, I tried floating and text-align. CSS makes me crazy...

I want my totals for each line to line up on the right with the subtotal and total, but I want the quantity and price to be much smaller and the item name to take up most of the width. And as the window size changes, I would prefer the quantity, price, and total to remain just as big as necessary and for the item name to always just take whatever width remains. And I want the line to never have to break into two lines, which was also sometimes happening. That just screws everything up worse...

Hopefully I'll have to edit the format of the HTML as little as possible or not at all because my JavaScript that does the math very much depends on that format. I tried adding a span and it broke my script and didn't look any better anyway. (The JavaScript is kind of picky because of how it has to be set up, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694668/how-might-i-do-javascript-math-on-a-varying-number-of-input-fields).)

Is there anything that can be done to get it the way I want it?

Here's what I've got:

```js
 function doInvoiceMath(line) {
  var wholeLine = line.parentNode; // Gets the <div>
  var fields = wholeLine.children; // Gets all the fields
  var quantity = fields[2].value; // Get the quantity
  var price = fields[3].value; // Get the value
  fields[4].innerHTML = "$" + Math.round((quantity * price)*100)/100; // Calculate the total for the total child: Math.round() * 100/100 will round to second decimal place
  var totals = document.getElementsByClassName("wpdsd_total");
  var runningTotal = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < totals.length; ++index){
   currentTotal = totals[index].innerHTML;
   while(currentTotal.charAt(0) === '$'){currentTotal = currentTotal.substr(1)}
   runningTotal = runningTotal + parseFloat(currentTotal);
  }
  document.getElementById("wpdsd_subtotal").innerHTML = Math.round(runningTotal * 100)/100;
 }
```

```css
 .wpdsd_line{
 }
 .wpdsd_item{
 }
 .wpdsd_qty{
 }
 .wpdsd_price{
 }
 .wpdsd_total{
 }
 #wpdsd_invoice_totals{
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wpdsd_line_titles">
 <span class="wpdsd_item_title">Item</span>
 <span class="wpdsd_qty_title">Quantity</span>
 <span class="wpdsd_price_title">Price</span>
 <span class="wpdsd_total_title">Total</span>
 </div>
   <div class="wpdsd_line">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_0" value="71">
  <input type="text" class="wpdsd_item" name="wpdsd_item_0" value="1m 8 Pin">
  <input type="number" class="wpdsd_qty" name="wpdsd_qty_0" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  $<input type="number" class="wpdsd_price" name="wpdsd_price_0" step="0.01" value="4" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  <span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_0">$0.00</span><br />
  </div>
    <div class="wpdsd_line">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_1" value="45">
  <input type="text" class="wpdsd_item" name="wpdsd_item_1" value="3m USB Type-C">
  <input type="number" class="wpdsd_qty" name="wpdsd_qty_1" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  $<input type="number" class="wpdsd_price" name="wpdsd_price_1" step="0.01" value="5.52" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  <span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_1">$0.00</span><br />
  </div>
    <div class="wpdsd_line">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_2" value="76">
  <input type="text" class="wpdsd_item" name="wpdsd_item_2" value="Wall Charger">
  <input type="number" class="wpdsd_qty" name="wpdsd_qty_2" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  $<input type="number" class="wpdsd_price" name="wpdsd_price_2" step="0.01" value="4.69" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  <span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_2">$0.00</span><br />
  </div>
    <div class="wpdsd_line">
  <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_3" value="78">
  <input type="text" class="wpdsd_item" name="wpdsd_item_3" value="car charger">
  <input type="number" class="wpdsd_qty" name="wpdsd_qty_3" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  $<input type="number" class="wpdsd_price" name="wpdsd_price_3" step="0.01" value="3.69" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
  <span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_3">$0.00</span><br />
  </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_number_of_lines" value="4">
 <div id="wpdsd_invoice_totals">
 Subtotal: $<span id="wpdsd_subtotal">0.00</span><br />
 Taxes: $<span id="wpdsd_taxes">0.00</span><br />
 Total: $<span id="wpdsd_total">0.00</span></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: can you simply say what you want us to help with im abit lost

Comment: I want to use CSS to make the widths of my input fields nicer. (Item line biggest, and responsive to the window size. Qty, price, and total just as big as they need to be, and the Totals lined up on the right).

Comment: why are you using divs then use the table layout :) you're making your job harder this way

Comment: The divs are there so that the Javascript can access the whole set of fields for a line at once.

Comment: it being a table doesnt stop you being able to do that

Comment: if you get confused on how to adapt your javascript to work with a table let me know but it shouldnt make any difference :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice would be to use a table

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

you can still select by class name and you can will have a more predicTABLE and more semantic markup

```js
function doInvoiceMath(startingPoint) {
  var startingTD = startingPoint.parentNode;
  var invoiceLine = startingTD.parentNode;
  var invoiceCells = invoiceLine.children;
  var quantityCell = invoiceCells[1].children;
  var quantity = quantityCell[0].value;
  var priceCell = invoiceCells[2].children;
  var price = priceCell[0].value;
  var totalCell = invoiceCells[3].children;
  totalCell[0].innerHTML = Math.round((quantity * price) * 100) / 100;
  var totals = document.getElementsByClassName("wpdsd_total");
  var runningTotal = 0;
  for (index = 0; index < totals.length; ++index) {
    currentTotal = totals[index].innerHTML;
    runningTotal = runningTotal + parseFloat(currentTotal);
  }
  document.getElementById("wpdsd_subtotal").innerHTML = Math.round(runningTotal * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementById("wpdsd_taxes").innerHTML = Math.round((document.getElementById("wpdsd_subtotal").innerHTML * 0.13) * 100) / 100;
  document.getElementById("wpdsd_total").innerHTML = Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById("wpdsd_subtotal").innerHTML) + parseFloat(document.getElementById("wpdsd_taxes").innerHTML)) * 100) / 100;
}
```

```css
#wpdsd_invoice_table {
  width: 100%;
}

.wpdsd_table_heading {
  text-align: left;
}

.wpdsd_white_space {
  color: white;
}

.wpdsd_product_cell {
  width: auto;
}

.wpdsd_product_cell input {
  width: 100%;
}

.wpdsd_quantity_cell {
  width: 110px;
}

.wpdsd_quantity_cell input {
  width: 100%;
}

.wpdsd_price_cell {
  width: 80px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.wpdsd_price_cell input {
  width: 90%;
}

.wpdsd_total_cell {
  text-align: right;
  width: 50px;
}

.wpdsd_totals_cell {
  text-align: right;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="wpdsd_invoice_table">
  <tr>
    <th class="wpdsd_table_heading">Item</th>
    <th class="wpdsd_table_heading">Quantity</th>
    <th class="wpdsd_table_heading"><span class="wpdsd_white_space">$</span>Price</th>
    <th class="wpdsd_total_cell">Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wpdsd_product_cell">
      <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_0" value="71">
      <input type="text" name="wpdsd_item_0" value="1m 8 Pin">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_quantity_cell">
      <input type="number" name="wpdsd_qty_0" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_price_cell">
      $<input type="number" name="wpdsd_price_0" step="0.01" value="4" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_total_cell">
      $<span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_0">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wpdsd_product_cell">
      <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_1" value="45">
      <input type="text" name="wpdsd_item_1" value="3m USB Type-C">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_quantity_cell">
      <input type="number" name="wpdsd_qty_1" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_price_cell">
      $<input type="number" name="wpdsd_price_1" step="0.01" value="5.52" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_total_cell">
      $<span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_1">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wpdsd_product_cell">
      <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_2" value="76">
      <input type="text" name="wpdsd_item_2" value="Wall Charger">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_quantity_cell">
      <input type="number" name="wpdsd_qty_2" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_price_cell">
      $<input type="number" name="wpdsd_price_2" step="0.01" value="4.69" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_total_cell">
      $<span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_2">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="wpdsd_product_cell">
      <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_ID_3" value="78">
      <input type="text" name="wpdsd_item_3" value="car charger">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_quantity_cell">
      <input type="number" name="wpdsd_qty_3" placeholder="Enter Qty" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_price_cell">
      $<input type="number" name="wpdsd_price_3" step="0.01" value="3.69" oninput="doInvoiceMath(this)">
    </td>
    <td class="wpdsd_total_cell">
      $<span class="wpdsd_total" id="wpdsd_total_3">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="wpdsd_totals_cell">
      <input type="hidden" name="wpdsd_number_of_lines" value="4"> Subtotal: $<span id="wpdsd_subtotal">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="wpdsd_totals_cell">
      Taxes: $<span id="wpdsd_taxes">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="wpdsd_totals_cell">
      Total: $<span id="wpdsd_total">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that tables are no longer best practice and that css should now be used instead... Is that incorrect?

Comment: yes you're right unless you're using a table as a table then you should use a table, tables aren't best practice when you're using them for layouts  like we used to 10 years ago

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like job for flexbox. Please, go to this link and try it: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

In my experience the best thing for handling items in same row is flexbox. For different sizes you can use max-width, on class or nth-child.

And, as you probably know, you can use media queries @media (max-width: somepx), to solve your responsive issues.

Comment: Does @media work when this is all nested inside of more divs? This code lives in a custom meta box on WordPress